Use aspect-ratio of parent element in @container
According to the MDN Web Docs, aspect-ratio should be able to be applied to @container. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it.
The context is that I want to fill an element with dynamic aspect ratio completely with an image.
I explicitly do not want to use object-fit: cover; for this, as the image will be cropped and the initially invisible area can no longer be displayed later with e.g. pan and zoom. A hidden overflow is therefore desired for the parent element.
I am also open to other suggestions. Thanks in advance!


div {
  overflow: hidden;
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: wrapper;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.landscape {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  width: 200px;
}

.portrait {
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
  height: 200px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@container wrapper (aspect-ratio < 1) {
  img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
<div class="landscape">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
</div>
<div class="portrait">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
</div>



Edit: Image for clarification


"Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it" - The portrait container does has a 9/16 ratio as seen in the posted snippet. Furthermore how do you expect a 16/9 image to fit in a 9/16 container? Please clarify

Thanks for your reply. The image should occupy 100% of the height of the container with an aspect ratio of 9/16 with an auto width. Of course, with this ratio, a large part of the image will be (deliberately) hidden.

I'm not sure why you don't want object-fit:cover? Based on your description it sounds like the ideal solution. Here I have made the image container resizable so you can see how it behaves at any aspect ratio. By default the images would be centred but I have added object-position: left top; to match your illustration.


div {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: lightcoral;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: 160px;
  resize: both;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: left top;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

img:hover {/* pan on hover */
  object-position: right bottom;
}

img:active {/* scale on mouse-down */
  transform:scale(2);
}
<div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
</div>(Resize me! Hover to pan, mouse-down to zoom.)



With a little bit of JS you can pan & zoom to your mouse position:


const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".imgwrap");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

divs.forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    // Get the bounding rectangle of the current div
    const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Calculate the cursor's position relative to the div
    let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
    let y = event.clientY - rect.top;

    // Clamp the values to ensure they are within bounds
    x = Math.max(0, Math.min(x, rect.width));
    y = Math.max(0, Math.min(y, rect.height));

    const xPercent = (x / rect.width) * 100;
    const yPercent = (y / rect.height) * 100;

    // Output the position
    div.style.setProperty("--x", xPercent + "%");
    div.style.setProperty("--y", yPercent + "%");
  });

  // Prevent dragging of the div itself
  div.addEventListener("dragstart", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
.imgwrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: lightcoral;
  aspect-ratio: 2/3;
  width: 200px;
  resize: both;
  --x: 0%;
  --y: 0%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

.imgwrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: left top;
}

.imgwrap img:hover {
  /* pan on hover */
  transition: object-position 100ms ease;
  object-position: var(--x) var(--y);
}

.imgwrap img:active {
  /* scale on mouse-down */
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  transform: scale(3);
  transform-origin: var(--x) var(--y);
}
  <div class="imgwrap">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
  </div>(Resize me! Hover to pan, mouse-down to zoom.)



But to answer your question about container queries: Use container-type: size; instead of container-type: inline-size;. inline-size refers to just the width whereas size considers both width and height (and both are needed to calc aspect-ratio).


div {
  overflow: hidden;
  container-type: size; /* <- changed this from inline-size */
  container-name: wrapper;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.landscape {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  width: 200px;
}

.portrait {
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
  height: 200px;
}

.dynamic {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  height: 200px;
  resize: both;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@container wrapper (aspect-ratio <= 1) {
  img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
<div class="landscape">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
</div>
<div class="portrait">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
</div>
The following is resizable and shows that the proposed @container solution is not as good as the object-fit one since it only really works at the fixed aspect sizes.
<div class="dynamic">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
</div>




Great! Thanks for the explanation about container-type: size and the aspect ratio query! Good to know. Regarding his desire of not using object-fit: cover, I think it's just because he wants to implement some zoom and pan functionalities.

The aspect-ratio condition in @container queries doesn't seem to
be implemented yet by most navigators, regarding
Can I use?'s entry about container queries.
But you've already got the portrait and landscape classes, so
you can probably do different rules without querying the aspect-ratio,
especially as it is fixed by yourself.
But you can still do queries on the width and then decide what to do.
Just keep in mind that if you want to switch automatically between
portrait and landscape, depending on the space available (width of the
container), then I think you'll have to add an inner div which contains
the image and your other tools to zoom and pan.
Here's a way to make your image use the height:


/* Google Material icons. */
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,200,0,0";

/* Optimize space used, as the code snippet is so small. */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image-box {
  overflow: hidden;
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: image-box;
  margin-bottom: .5em; /* Optimize space used, as the code snippet is so small. */
  background: lightcoral;
  line-height: 0; /* To avoid space below the image. */
  position: relative; /* To put the buttons absolute. */
}

.image-box.landscape {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.image-box.portrait {
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
  max-height: 200px;
}

/* All images should never be wider than the container. */
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-box.portrait img {
  max-width: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  /* Proposition to center the image horizontally: */
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.image-box .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  font-size: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.image-box.landscape .buttons {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.image-box button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.image-box button:hover {
  color: white;
}

/* You can't use aspect-ratio in the condition because it's
   not yet implemented in most browsers. So use the
   portrait/landscape classes instead and do other specific
   rules based on the width of the conainer. */
@container image-box (width < 200px) {
  /* Reduce the size of the buttons. */
  /* cqi = 1% of a query container's inline size. */
  .image-box.landscape button {
    font-size: min(24px, 16cqi);
  }
  .image-box.portrait button {
    font-size: min(24px, 20cqi);
  }
}
<div class="image-box landscape">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="material-symbols-outlined">zoom_in</button>
    <button class="material-symbols-outlined">zoom_out</button>
    <button class="material-symbols-outlined">download</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image-box portrait">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1722932319520-fdd0c213bf2c?q=80&w=2940&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="material-symbols-outlined">zoom_in</button>
    <button class="material-symbols-outlined">zoom_out</button>
    <button class="material-symbols-outlined">download</button>
  </div>
</div>



Notice that I replaced your div selector by .image-box so
that it can't break other divs used for other purpose.
I didn't think about the centred vertical alignment of the image
in the landscape mode. We perhaps have to also use transforms
or other CSS techniques.
